# how really Cross Document Messaging in HTML5 overcome same-origin policy that apply to XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, html, cross-domain, distributed-computing, restful-architecture

I am new, I am developing an application that uses distributed resource.

I have one server called "presentation server" which serves everything related to template and ajax application (css, images, js, ...)

The second server only for serving raw data (let say, when you send a "GET /resources/a-resource", it return "text/plain, 'abc' "), actually I am developing an embedded RESTful interface on a device.

I have a client that connects to the first server, downloads the template. Then, the ajax code retrieves raw data from second server and present to user using the template.

I have a cross-domain problem with ajax here I know. I also know some current solution such as jquery or script tag.

What I am really concerning here is the Cross Document Messaging capability of HTML5. But what I found is just, they open two windows (a window + an Iframe or a window + a window) and passing message between each other.

it is not really like one sending a "GET" to some other and process the returned data, like XMLHttpRequest did.

Please show me how really Cross-document-messaging in HTML5 can over come my problem.

** In short, My pain here is the XMLHttpRequest did truely send a GET to other source but the Cross-document-messaging does not(as I know), I wander if HTML5 with Cross-document-messaging is able to do as XMLHttpRequest in sending a GET to other domain or not

I really thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I found is just, they open two windows (a window + an Iframe or a window + a window) and passing message between each other.

That's not true. You can have multiple iframe's in a document, each coming from a different domain, and all of them can post and receive messages from each other. So you don't need to have the pages in completely separate windows.

Also since you control both the presentation and API server, you can just set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) header on the API server to only accepts clients coming from your presentation server. That will allow you to use AJAX as you normally would.

Comment: Yeah, I am not concerning about IFrame because I just wanna know how to send a GET to my API server, IFrame + Cross-Document-Messaging does not solve the GET. That's my point.

Comment: Also, like you said, it is not HTML5 + Cross document messaging that solve the problem right? so it cannot solve my problem and I have to forget the HTML5 + its stupid Cross document messaging stuff?

Comment: I have read your recommend and I wander if it is capable for other web browser as well? like Chrome or IE or Safari?

Comment: iframe + cdm solves your problem like this - presentation iframe sends a message to the api iframe asking for some data. the api iframe will make a call to the api server with full access as its coming from the same domain. when it gets the data, it will post a message to the presentation iframe. the presentation iframe will receive the message, verify the sender, and then proceed with using the contents of the message.

Comment: @nhong - here's an article talking about [cross-browser implementations](http://www.refreshthenet.com/2010/05/26/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

Comment: oh you save my life --> " the api iframe will make a call to the api server with full access as its coming from the same domain", thank you so much for this sentence, I have never thought about it :X:X